# how to define variable based on a checkbox using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am trying to generate a checkbox that will define a variable x based on whether a checkbox is checked or not checked.  If the checkbox is checked then the variable equals myvalue and if the checkbox is unchecked the variable equals "No Value".  How do I tweak the below code to get the desired result?

```html
<html>
<body>

Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" value="myvalue"     onclick="myFunction()">

<p>Click the "Try it" button to display the value of the value attribute of the checkbox.</p>



<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

function myFunction() {
    if (x == null){
      var x = "NO value"
    }
    else
    {
      var x = document.getElementById("myCheck").value
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myCheck").checked;
var  output = document.getElementById("myCheck").value;
if (!x){
  output = "No Value";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = output;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the context of the element by adding a parameter 'this' in the function. So, your onclick function will look like - myFunction(this). Now, receive this parameter in the function as 'element' and inside the if condition, check this - '!element.checked'.
This should fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your code specifically to the checkbox and test if it is checked (or not checked) -- then update the value of the variable 'x'

```js
// get the checkbox and declare the 'x' variable
const myCheck = document.getElementById('myCheck');
let x = 'No Value';
// bind the checkbox to its change event, run some
// code when it changes from checked to un-checked
myCheck.onchange = function(){
   // update the value for 'x'
   // if checked, assign the checkbox's value
   // if not checked, assign 'No Value'
   x = (this.checked)? this.value : 'No Value';
   console.log( x );
};
```

```html
<label>Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" value="myvalue"></label>
```